# Getting "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'" with mechanicalsoup's submit function

Tags: python, attributeerror, mechanicalsoup

I am new to python and I'm attempting to use it to automate a manual form-filling task at work.

I am utilizing mechanicalsoup functions to navigate a website and fill out the same form using values from a csv file. I can confirm the code below works for the first row of values from my csv, but breaks after that. My csv file has three columns.

I would really appreciate any help with this. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
#login
import mechanicalsoup
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("<some website url>")
browser.select_form('form[action="/logins"]')
browser["username"] = "***"
browser["password"] = "*****"
browser.submit_selected()

#navigate to form and fill
def myfunction(esp, supnum, mid):
    url_esp = "<some website url>" + esp
    browser.open(url_esp)
    browser.follow_link("<some link>")
    url_facility = browser.get_url()
    url_facility_edit = url_facility + "<some link>"
    browser.open(url_facility_edit)
    browser.select_form('form[id="edit_facility"]')
    browser["facility[oracle_identifier]"] = supnum
    browser["facility[ffc_identifier]"] = mid
    response = browser.submit_selected()

#import values from csv to pass into function
import csv
with open('biweekly_oracle_esp_test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        esp = row[0]
        supnum = row[1]
        mid = row[2]
        myfunction(esp, supnum, mid)
```

Here is the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "open_file_test2.py", line 32, in <module>
>     myfunction(esp, supnum, mid)
>   File "open_file_test2.py", line 19, in myfunction
>     response = browser.submit_selected()
>   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\stateful_browser.py", line 232, in submit_selected
>     *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\browser.py", line 213, in submit
>     response = self._request(form, url, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\browser.py", line 155, in _request
>     data.setdefault(name, []).append(value)
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
> ```

Comment: The error is happening internally to MechanicalSoup, so maybe a bug in it.

Comment: https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup/issues/158

Comment: When you say that you know its working for the first row, you have successfully inspected the submitted form data on the other end of the wire? Because it looks to me like it's breaking on the **submit**. You should inspect the `browser` object in a debugger and look at the properties.

Comment: I have successfully inspected the submitted form. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'` occurs when you try to get an `append` method for a string. Strings do not have an `append` method. For example, the following throws an error: `s = "hello";  s.append("world")`